# Moving javascripts from body to head

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm currently trying to learn javascript, but I've got some problems that I can't seem to solve.

I'm working with a script that's meant to show todays date, and it works fine until i try to create a function and move it to the head of the document. This is the initial code that was working(without the function):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

    <p id="p1">
        <script>
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = Date();
        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

When i try to move the script up and create a function, nothing happens. I'd really appreciate if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong. This is what my current code with the function looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function setDate(){
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = Date();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id=”p1”> Todays date is: <script> setDate() </script> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there an error in your browser's console? But you should not have curly, or smart, quotes, use a proper programming editor or IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with moving the script.

You changed the `id` of the paragraph.

In the original code, the ID is `p1` and it is delimited with quote marks.

In the new code, the ID is `”p1”` and you do not have quote marks or apostrophes delimiting it.

(i.e. you have `U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` where before you had 
 `U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK`)

Comment: Okay,  I edited it and I got my function to work, but the "Todays date is" does not show up before the function. Why is that?

Comment: @wznd — Because you replaced the `innerHTML` (including the `Todays date is:` text with the new value. Change the content of a span instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said you are not using the correct quotation marks. As well as you are not closing your functions curly braces again.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in the above code:

1. Missing closing curly bracket for setState()
2. The quotation mark for p tag should be ""

Your "Today's date" will not be displayed because inside setDate() you are replacing the entire content of the p tag.
To display the "Toda's date" write it outside the p tag

Comment: Thank you so much.